# Pihole: Redirect domain to ip (Hostrecord doesn't work)

Tags: raspbian, pi-hole

Pihole is like an own DNS Server. So it must be possible to edit and add domains. I want to connect the domain `my.domain` with the ip `my.own.ip.adress`.

That means I enter `my.domain` to my browser and get redirected `my.own.ip.adress`.

**How can I do this? Is there a DNS list or any file I can edit?**

All this happens in my local network.

I tried using

```
sudo pihole -a hostrecord my.domain my.own.ip.adress
```

and

```
pihole restartdns
```

This works when I do (It shows my.own.ip.adress)

```
dig my.domain
```

But it's **not accessable via browser**. (I tried it from multiple devices and also cleared all browser caches, nothing changed)

My 01-pihole.conf file is this:

```
server=1.1.1.1
server=1.0.0.1
domain-needed
bogus-priv
host-record=my.domain,my.own.ip.adress
interface=eth0
server=/fritz.box/192.168.5.1
server=/5.168.192.in-addr.arpa/192.168.5.1
```

Comment: upvote for improving the question

Comment: `my.domain` have a web-server running ? If dig find the IP associated with your domain it's probably a problem on the web-server side. What is your response in your web-browser network tool when you call your domain , what is the HTTP error code , or other errors ?

Comment: @Ephemeral The Error in my browser is: Server not found. my.domain doesn't has a web-server running.

Comment: Ok. What are you trying to join as a service by putting the IP address or the domain name in the browser in this case ?

Comment: @Ephemeral I have a dlan device in my network. I can configure it by entering the local ip. But I want to enter a (self created) domain name.

Comment: @Jakob, Have you try to put `192.168.5.X     my.domain` in your `/etc/hosts` file ? (where `192.168.5.X` is your dlan Ipv4 addr if i understand correctly) Close and reopen your browser after this file modification (maybe also clear the cache). Or you can use [this](https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/howto-using-pi-hole-as-lan-dns-server/533) for dnsmasq.

Comment: @Ephemeral Thanks for your answer(comment). I tried both ways, but none of them helped. (I also cleared my browser cache)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102644/discussion-between-ephemeral-and-jakob).

Comment: Since version 5, the `sudo pihole -a hostrecord` does not work anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's been a while. I believe PiHole has added a new function to officially support this.

Now, you can configure a "local DNS" on the PiHole admin panel. I'm running PiHole V5.12, FTL V5.17 and Web Interface V5.14.2.
It's accessible on /admin/dns_records.php. Along the same lines, you can now access your PiHole admin pannel through pi.hole, thanks to this.

Just putting this here for anyone who may be asking the same question